# Javascript new Date() accepts dates beyond end of month

Tags: javascript, date

I'm using JavaScipt's `new Date(datestring)` to parse user input on IE11.

The specific line of code is

```
var date = new Date(enteredText);
```

It accepts any parameter for day field - for example, `5/50/1997` parses to `June 19, 1997`, because June 19 would be the 50th day of May.

Is there a way to force it to not do this and to only accept real dates?

Comment: You could check the value before you create the date object. But I tried it in chrome and I couldn´t create a date with a day greater 30/31. It returned    "Invalid Date"

Comment: You'll need to parse the date yourself.  If you pass an invalid date string to the date constructor, [browsers are free to interpret as they please](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2): _"If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats."_

Comment: Different browsers treat the date function differently. Some returns a date some return invalid date.

Comment: The `Date` object is fundamentally broken in JavaScript, if you need to work with dates on the frontend I suggest using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), the extra bytes will save you a ton of time and headaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to parse the string on your own to verify if the date is valid. To do this you will need to split the string by a `delimiter` ('/' in this case) and check each day/month/year is valid.

Where you put this validation is entirely up to you. You can override the `Date` constructor using `Date.prototype.constructor = function(){/*your code here*/}` or you can create a custom function that validates the string before instantiating a new date `function validateDate(str){/*your code here*/}`. The latter is probably your best bet.

Comment: Hmmph.  Seems a bit unreasonable to write a date parsing routine before calling the built-in date parsing routine.  Ah, JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

You can split the parameter passed by '/' or depending on your delimiter is and manually check if the date, month and year is valid before passing it to the date function